# Angular, ngRoute, routeProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-boot, angular-routing

Good morning! I'm trying to make angular applicatiom with spring boot. I did back end with spring boot but when I started doing front end with Angular I got some misunderstanding. I got some errors in my browser and I cannot understand what errors and what they mean. I was searching whole stackoverflow and didn't find anything about that.

My book.html and book.js are:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApps',['ngRoute']).

config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/books/',
        { templateUrl:'/book/list'}

    )}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-app="myApps">

    <h1>Hello</h1>



    <data-ng-view>

    </data-ng-view>



</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apelo/book.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

list.html which should be in book.html when I go to url with routeProvider is:

```html
<table >
    <thead>

    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name Book</td>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></td>

    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr data-ng-repeat="book in book">
        <td>{book.id{}}</td>
        <td>{{book.name}}<td>
        <td>{{book.author}}</td>
        <td>{{book.count}}</td>
        <td><i class="icon-edit"></i></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And after this all I try to run and got this:
[image: browser tool errors]

Please, notice that I defined in book.js $locationProvider in html5Mode(true);, but anyway I have to put # in url for rendering page, I'm trying without it but I got json value from back end.

I tried everything what I could but anyway have not found. I hope you could find out what's happening.

<-- UPDATED -->

After delete .min from all scripts I got new broser console errors.

[image]

Comment: The first error shows your book.js failed to load.Did you cross check the location of book.js file

Comment: It's most likely an error with `book.js`path, as @jithin stated the first GET error tells you that browser can't load the file.

Comment: But how path of book.js can be wrong if I created path with hitting alt + enter in Intelijj and book.js too. I can send paths.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use a minified version of angular when you are developing an 
app to see described errors in browsers console:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apelo/book.js"></script>
```

**Update:**

when you add service's strings before function to be minification 
safe you should write all injected services:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApps',['ngRoute']).

config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/books/',
        { templateUrl:'/book/list'}

    )}]);
```

Comment: I did as you said and it's really there are a lot of errors in browser console but why? I did exactly like from tutorials and I see these errors I feel that there is no angular at all in my apllication now, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

In `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` you will need to set a `<base>` in the `<head>` of your document that link around your application using relative links.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

you will also need to manage server configuration for routing redirection. Here is a great link which i used to solve my issue. 
[Deep Linking AngularJS](https://coderwall.com/p/mycbiq/deep-linking-angularjs-on-windows-azure-iis).

Happy coding..